# jQuery - Can threads/asynchronous be done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, asynchronous

I'm currently using `AJAX` with `Django` Framework.

I can pass `asynchronous` POST/GET to `Django`, and let it return a `json` object.

Then according to the result passed from `Django`, I will loop through the data, and update a table on the webpage.

The HTML for the table:

```
<!-- Modal for Variable Search-->
<div class="modal fade" id="variableSearch" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Variable Name Search</h4>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table id="variableSearchTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Variable Name </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <p>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" id="variableSearchProgressBar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
                        <span class="sr-only">0% Complete</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p>
            <p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="addSearchVariable" >Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="variableSearchDataCloseButton" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically it is a `bootstrap 3` modal, with `jQuery DataTable`, and with a progress bar to show the user the current progress.

The Javascript that is used to get Django results:

```
$('#chartSearchVariable').click(function(event)
{
    $('#chartConfigModal').modal("hide");
    $('#variableSearch').modal("show");

    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    var blockname = document.getElementById('chartConfigModalBlockname').value;

    $('#variableSearchProgressBar').css('width', "0%").attr('aria-valuenow', "0%");

    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"GET",
        url:"ajax_retreiveVariableNames/",
        timeout: 4000000,
        data:
        {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken,
            'blockname':blockname
        },
        success: function(response)
        {
            if(response.status == "invalid")
            {
                $('#chartConfigModal').modal("hide");
                $('#variableSearch').modal("hide");
                $('#invalid').modal("show");
            }
            else
            {
                configurationVariableChart.row('').remove().draw(false);
                for (i = 0 ; i < response.variables.length; i++)
                {
                    configurationVariableChart.row.add(
                    $(
                        '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + response.variables[i] + '</td>' +
                        '<tr>'
                    )[0]);
                }
                configurationVariableChart.draw();
                $('#variableSearchProgressBar').css('width', "100%").attr('aria-valuenow', "100%");
            }
        },
        failure: function(response)
        {
            $('#chartConfigModal').modal("hide");
            $('#variableSearch').modal("hide");
            $('#invalid').modal("show");
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$('#addSearchVariable').click(function(event)
{
    $('#variableSearch').modal("hide");
    $('#chartConfigModal').modal("show");
    document.getElementById('chartConfigModalVariable').value = currentVariableNameSelects;
});

$('#variableSearchDataCloseButton').click(function(event)
{
    $('#variableSearch').modal("hide");
    $('#chartConfigModal').modal("show");
});
```

The problem is with the updating table part:

```
    configurationVariableChart.row('').remove().draw(false);
    for (i = 0 ; i < response.variables.length; i++)
    {
        configurationVariableChart.row.add(
        $(
            '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + response.variables[i] + '</td>' +
            '<tr>'
        )[0]);
    }
    configurationVariableChart.draw();
    $('#variableSearchProgressBar').css('width', "100%").attr('aria-valuenow', "100%");
```

Since the response.variables can be over 10k, and it will freeze the web browser, even though it is still drawing.

I'm pretty new to Web Design (less than 4 months), but I assume it's because they are all running on the same thread.

Is there a way in Javascript to do threading/async? I had a search, and the results were deferred/promise which seems very abstract at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try processing retrieved data incrementally.

At piece below , elements generated in blocks of 250 , primarily utilizing jQuery [deferred.notify()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.notify/) and [deferred.progress()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.progress/).

When all 10,000 items processed , the `deferred` object is `resolved` with the collection of 10,000 elements.  The elements are then added to `document` at single call to `.html()` within [deferred.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)'s `.done()` callback ; `.fail()` callback cast as `null` .

Alternatively , could append elements to the `document` in blocks of 250 , within `deferred.progress` callback ; instead of at the single call within `deferred.done` , which occurs upon completion of the entire task.

`setTimeout` is utilized to prevent "freeze the web browser" condition .

```js
$(function() {
// 10k items 
var arr = $.map(new Array(10000), function(v, k) {
  return v === undefined ? k : null
});
  
var len = arr.length;
var dfd = new $.Deferred();
// collection of items processed at `for` loop in blocks of 250
var fragment = [];
var redraw = function() {
  for (i = 0 ; i < 250; i++)
    {
        // configurationVariableChart.row.add(
        // $(
        fragment.push('<tr>' +
                '<td>' + arr[i] + '</td>' +
            '</tr>')
        // )[0]);
    };
    arr.splice(0, 250);
    console.log(fragment, arr, arr.length);
    return dfd.notify([arr, fragment])
};

$.when(redraw())
// `done` callbacks
.then(function(data) {
  $("#results").html(data.join(","));
  delete fragment;
}
  // `fail` callbacks      
 , null
  // `progress` callbacks
 , function(data) {
  // log ,  display `progress` of tasks
     console.log(data);
     $("progress").val(data[1].length);
     $("output:first").text(Math.floor(data[1].length / 100) + "%");
     $("output:last").text(data[1].length +" of "+ len + " items processed");
     $("#results").html("processing data...");
     if (data[0].length) {
         var s = setTimeout(function() {
             redraw()
         }, 100)
     } else {
       clearTimeout(s);
       dfd.resolve(data[1]);
     }
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress min="0" max="10000"></progress><output for="progress"></output>
<output for="progress"></output><br />
<table id="results"></table>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ess28zLh/

Answer (score 1):

Deferreds/promises won't help you here. JS in the browser is always single-threaded.

The trick is not to build up DOM elements via JS. That is always going to be expensive and slow. Rather than passing data in JSON from Django and building up a DOM dynamically, you should get Django to render a template fragment on the server side and pass that whole thing to the front-end, where the JS can simply insert it at the relevant point.

Comment: Are there any alternatives than doing this? Because the whole page is dynamic, meaning some tables are created by JS, and then populated using AJAX. There's no refresh in the process?

Comment: But that's why I said to render a fragment, not the whole page. Each table can still be a separate Ajax call, but the server returns a block of HTML which you insert.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Why bother? Why not just use the existing data and generate the template on the frontend and append it once? Why mix up data and HTML between client and server?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think I know what you mean, trying to generate HTML on the server side, and put in on the client. I could do that, but I'm trying not do to this, because I think data is only what the server should pass.