# Grab first tenth list of Ajax return

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I got a huge html file aprox 200MB (mycartoonlist.html) which I should grab by AJAX and append it in a specific ID. Here is my ajax:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {           
       $.ajax({
            url: "mycartoonlist.html",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                $("#cartoonlisting").html(data);

                console.log(data);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert(textStatus)
            }
        });

 });
```

The above Ajax generates thousands of list like the following:

```
<div id="1" class="list">Cartoon abc</div>
<div id="2" class="list">Cartoon mnk</div>
<div id="3" class="list">Cartoon klo</div>
......................
<div id="10000988" class="list">Carton zzz</div>
```

That will be injected into:

```
<div id="cartoonlisting"></div>
```

I know I can't inject all those list into my #cartoonlisting that will be crashing my browser, thus I just want **the first tenth to be injected into #cartoonlisting**

Any suggest or comments will be appreciated.

Oouch and I can't do server side scripting to split the mycartoonlist.html into pieces

**My Solution:**

Instead of using basic .ajax, I use .load() Ajax method, like following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#cartoonlisting").load("mycartoonlist.html #1,#2,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9,#10")
});
```

the above short of code is just the idea how I inject the html and choose some elements from thousands of it.in my case

Comment: Do you have access to the server?  Or is this an outside list that you're grabbing?  If you can modify what is passed that's the best way to do it.  If not, just try to limit your data before doing any kind of DOM manipulation.

Comment: @Gregory Is requirement to append _1000099_ `div` elements to `#cartoonlisting` ?

Comment: @guest271314 yes, I should append on that divs into #cartoonlisting but not at once, the idea is pieces by pieces off the big chunk.

Comment: @WakeskaterX like I said in my question I do not have access to the server and do php script to slice the html. Yes, I am aware in the first place that limiting the data before injected to the DOM is a must, thankyou :)

Comment: @Gregory See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068821/jquery-can-threads-asynchronous-be-done/

Comment: @guest271314 Yes if I make another mycartoonlist.html -> mycartoonlist-2.html (~2Kb) with consist only 20 divs, just blank when I append mycartoonlist.html, the real deal data is that big html chunk

Comment: If `data` is returned to browser , approach could be to only append 100 - 250 elements at a time , when that completes , move to next ; until all elements appended.

Comment: @guest271314 thanks, I see your accepted answer, I need to take a while to extract that information for my lazy brain :D, thankyou.

Comment: @Gregory Since appear `div` elements have `id`'s , another approach could be to utilize `.load()` to request n number of `div` elements - instead of entire file; e.g.; `$("#cartoonlisting").load("mycartoonlist.html #1")` ->  `$("#cartoonlisting").load("mycartoonlist.html #10000988")` , incrementally.

Comment: @guest271314 getting there almost. Now I can do dynamically like $("#cartoonlisting").load("mycartoonlist.html #1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9,#10")

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a [Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header to your request, but it wouldn't be as verbose as specifying the number of lines. You'd have to know the length of each line which could be difficult on dynamic content. You could get the file size and then bring back one tenth of the file size in bytes. Then you'd need to clean up any invalid markup before parsing and appending to the DOM.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {           
       $.ajax({
            url: "mycartoonlist.html",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            headers: { "Range": "bytes=0-1000" },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                // clean up data before inserting into DOM
                $("#cartoonlisting").append($(data));

                console.log(data);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert(textStatus)
            }
        });
 });
```

Comment: thanks @cameron-tinker for a quick reply. But headers with bytes will be hurting my code :), my next step is about building pagination from this

Comment: I've tried : $(data).find('.list').each(function(){           $('#cartoonlisting').append($(this).html()); }); but no luck, must be something to do with :first-child, .first(), .children()

Comment: Is the problem that 200MB loaded into the DOM is crashing your browser? I guess I misunderstood the problem if you're not having an issue with loading the 200MB HTML.

Comment: If you uses the `Range` header for pagination like `/* get next items */ Range: bytes=1000-2000` you will have invalid markup at the beginning and the end of every request. If you remove them you will loose the last item from request #1 that was trimmed and the same item on request #2 at the beginning. So you won't get all items...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In that case, I'd recommend another approach for pagination. It seems that you should be able to load 200MB of HTML safely into the DOM of modern browsers. It was unclear from the question that the problem surrounded pagination.

Comment: @CameronTinker yes, it is the problem about pagination also, the idea is when I'm able to grab first 10 then I should be able to get the rest. I could be misunderstood when 200MB of mycartoonlist.html is there in the server and I slice piece by pieces into user browser that would not be a problem. So instead of build up mycartoonlist.html into pieces, I slice off that big chunk

Answer (score 2):

> you can collect all the information coming from mycartoonlist.html in
>   a json object , and then iterate the json object using foreach loop
>   and display only the tenth index data to the div id
>   "**cartoonlisting**"

Comment: thanks @shelly that would be a firm solution, but now I am facing the only data I got is that .html and yeah that is 200MB :(

Answer (score 1):

I am amazed that 200MB is not crashing your browser but here is a possible solution anyways:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Where do we start and how far do we go?
   var start = 20000;
   var go = 10;

   $.ajax({
        url: "mycartoonlist.html",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            // clear! bzzt
            $("#cartoonlisting").html('');

            // Loop through the DIVs and see if their index is in your range
            $(data).find('div.list').each(function(){
                if($(this).index() >= start && $(this).index() <= (start + go)){
                    $("#cartoonlisting").append($(this).clone());
                }
            });

            console.log(data);
            console.log(jqXHR);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(textStatus)
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I've tried.. but no luck, but I will start from this, thankyou