# List with 3500+ items is loaded via ajax a small bunch at a time. Stops updating in the UI, but I see the li tags being appended in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

<strike>I have a use case where there are thousands of items on a list shown to the user. They are loaded a small batch at a time and I see the network traffic going in and out, I see data getting loaded. I see the DOM getting bigger, but the list itself in the UI stops updating (Chrome).</strike>

When I examine it, I see thousands of items in the code, when I select the items through console and make it count them, I see the proper number. But in the page itself, I don't see these items get displayed. The list uses drag-and-drop to put items from it into another list (and load additional data about them).

Not using jquery.datatables at the moment, but been meaning to migrate to them a long time ago. I can’t find a good example, though, everything I see uses pagination to split, but what if this is not an option?

How can I pinpoint what it is that is preventing the items from display? The number of entries will vary between 500 and 20 000.

Never mind. everything works as intended, duh. I was stupid and missed something very obvious: things had "display: none" for a very good reason about which I totally forgot (has to do with the core logic of the application). Next time hit me with a stick so I could remember to pay more attention.

Comment: You want us to debug your code, with out any examples? How exactly are you doing this? What methods are you useing? This is a hypothetical question at this point.

Comment: Can include `js` at Question ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068821/jquery-can-threads-asynchronous-be-done/

Comment: Uhh. I was stupid. There's no issue, just missed something to which I should have paid attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you meant by saying 'DOM getting bigger' but 'don't see items get displayed'. 
Typically JS has a main thread which will handle functions/callbacks as well as view-refresh. So if you operation is blocking , the view will not be refreshing.

As for the pagination is not an option thing, you can consider using DOM-lazy-Loading mechanism where you only put what should be in the **current viewport** into the dom. As user scroll, you calculate the scroll height dynamically to add/remove items to/from the DOM. One thing to remember is you typically need to define a **fixed height** for your rows so that you could do the calculation. This lazy-loading way is a common way of solving this type of problem and is widely used by different frameworks like GXT, angular-gird..etc.

Comment: Thanks. There is no problem here, I was just stupid, but this answer pointed me in the right direction so that I could notice what’s actually not wrong. Should inspect DOM more carefully.