# array with numbers (5+million)

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

i need a "list" with a number range starting at 0 and ending with around 5 million. I also have to display this within a webbrowser, so i tried javascript and php. Of course, while "loading" all numbers, the browser crashes. Is there a way to prevent that? To actually make it work within a browser? I guess Javascript isnt the right language, but how could i solve this? Help would be appreciated :)

Here is the code so far

```
function range()
{
    var array = [];
    var start = (arguments[0] ? arguments[0] : 0);
    var end   = (arguments[1] ? arguments[1] : 9);
    if (start == end) { array.push(start); return array; }
    var inc   = (arguments[2] ? Math.abs(arguments[2]) : 1);
    inc *= (start > end ? -1 : 1);
    for (var i = start; (start < end ? i <= end : i >= end) ; i += inc)
        array.push(i);
    return array;
}

var foo = range(1, 5607249)

for(var i=0;i<foo.length;i++){
  document.write(foo[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to display 5 million numbers at the same time? Language isn't the problem here. Storing 42MB of doubles isn't a problem either.

Comment: *the browser crashes* crashes how? What errors (if any) do you see? Which browser? Which version? Did you try other browsers? 5 million isn't that much, you ought to be able to handle it.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. What is the use case?

Comment: also, `document.write` is probably a really bad choice here too.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Hmm if language and size aren't a problem, why isnt it working then? Oh, i need it for a project ;) Basically, i want them to be "all" loaded at the end, they dont need to load at the same time..

Comment: 5 million document.writes, bad choice. Writing to the screen once, better choice.

Comment: Try processing data in increments , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068821/jquery-can-threads-asynchronous-be-done

Comment: @MattBurland both chrome and safari crash. (both the latest version) no further errors, just the "oh no" which chrome displays when it crashes. jaa, i thought that would be an easy thing to do...

Comment: @guest271314 !! ohh looks good! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to display that much data without crashing the browser is to implement some kind of pagination system. Meaning, only show a chunk of your results at a time. You can do this by setting a maximum number of results to show at a time and tracking a page number.

```js
function range()
{
    var array = [];
    var start = (arguments[0] ? arguments[0] : 0);
    var end   = (arguments[1] ? arguments[1] : 9);
    if (start == end) { array.push(start); return array; }
    var inc   = (arguments[2] ? Math.abs(arguments[2]) : 1);
    inc *= (start > end ? -1 : 1);
    for (var i = start; (start < end ? i <= end : i >= end) ; i += inc)
        array.push(i);
    return array;
}

var foo = range(1, 5607249);
var results = document.querySelector('.results');
var page = 0;
var PAGE_LENGTH = 100;
function showResults() {
  var start = page * PAGE_LENGTH;
  var end = start + PAGE_LENGTH;
  // Write them all at once and put line breaks between them
  results.innerHTML = foo.slice(start, end).join('<br />');
}

document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Make sure we don't go past the first page
  page = Math.max(0, page - 1);
  showResults();
});
document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Don't go past the end of the results 
  page = Math.min(page + 1, foo.length / PAGE_LENGTH - 1);
  showResults();
});

showResults();
```

```html
<div class="results"></div>
<button class="prev">Prev</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Yes, thats awesome! Thank you soo much for your effort!