# Speed up a for loop text replace in a large dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, after dynamically adding thousands of rows to a table with an AJAX call, at the end of that, I wanted to go through the whole table and replace the date data with a human readable format. FYI, the call adds 50 rows per second, (API limit).

```
    var t = document.getElementById('theTable');
    for(var i=1;i<t.rows.length;i++) {
      dateOld = $("tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child(3)").text();
      myDate = new Date( dateOld *1000);
      $("tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child(3)").text(myDate.toLocaleString());
      dateOld2 = $("tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child(4)").text();
      myDate = new Date( dateOld2 *1000);
      $("tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child(4)").text(myDate.toLocaleString());
    }
```

When I run this script once the table is filled, it takes a few seconds on under 1000 rows, but once it gets over 5000 rows it just takes a long time, or even worse, 15000, it just crashes after trying to do it for several minutes.

Any tips on how to make this script faster running?

Also, I've had it in the for loop, that used to replace it row by row

```
  success: function (apiResponse){
   for(var item in apiResponse.response.sessions){
     var row = $('<tr>');
     $('#theTable tr:first th').each(function(){
      var td = "<td>" + apiResponse.response.sessions[item][$(this).text()] + "</td>";
      row.append(td);
     });
     $(row[0].outerHTML).appendTo("#theTable");
     dateOld = $("tr:last-child td:nth-child(3)").text();
     myDate = new Date( dateOld *1000);
     $("tr:last-child td:nth-child(3)").text(myDate.toLocaleString());
     dateOld2 = $("tr:last-child td:nth-child(4)").text();
     myDate2 = new Date( dateOld2 *1000);
     $("tr:last-child td:nth-child(4)").text(myDate2.toLocaleString());
   }
```

Maybe doing it all in a batch in the end was a bad decision, so I've decided to provide the old code, that does it row by row once its added. But adding new rows to the table got super slow once the table reached 3000 rows, because of keeping this code in the "for" loop.

Perhaps there is a better solution that these two?
Another question - would it help to hide the table while its being populated until its ready? Just display:none on the table? No difference?
Thanks

Comment: Try processing data incrementally, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068821/jquery-can-threads-asynchronous-be-done/

Comment: Thats an interesting suggestion, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to convert dates on fly. You can do it in your success handler.

```
  success: function (apiResponse){
   for(var item in apiResponse.response.sessions){
     var row = $('<tr />');
     $('#theTable tr:first th').each(function(ind){//ind will be in use
       var val = apiResponse.response.sessions[item][$(this).text()];
       row.append($("<td />").html(function(){
                     if(ind == 2 || ind == 3){//nth-child(3) and (4)
                        return (new Date(val * 1000)).toLocaleString();
                     }
                     else
                       return val;
                  })); 
     });
     row.appendTo('#theTable');
     }//for(item
     /* no need any more
     $(row[0].outerHTML).appendTo("#theTable");
     dateOld = $("tr:last-child td:nth-child(3)").text();
     myDate = new Date( dateOld *1000);
     $("tr:last-child td:nth-child(3)").text(myDate.toLocaleString());
     dateOld2 = $("tr:last-child td:nth-child(4)").text();
     myDate2 = new Date( dateOld2 *1000);
     $("tr:last-child td:nth-child(4)").text(myDate2.toLocaleString());
     */
   }//success
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should format the source data before you generate the html text, cause the performance of manipulating the dom is bad. and you join the string by using a array like this:

```
var arr = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', ...],
list = [];

for (var i = 0,
l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    list[list.length] = '' + arr[i] + '';
}
list = '' + list.join('') + '';
```

in this case  the performance will be improve . Last but not least, paging is a good choice when you have thousands of rows, becase the browser need time to render, and that's bad performance!

Comment: Not sure what to make of this generic code. you said that I should format the source data, but you haven't showed how to do that, if I knew how,  I would try to do that, but I know only how to edit the DOM. Also, is it no problems if the array has 10-30 thousand items in there, each with 20 td's? So an array of 200,000 - 600,000 td's with text in them. Wont it crash when I try to append it all to html? Also, pagination is not an option, its a internal use only table which is intended to be all visible and copyable to excel, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: just format apiResponse.response.sessions[item][$(this).text()] before you adding to html, if you have such a huge data, you really need pagination and the search function to get the information, like I said the browser need time to render, and that's bad performance! and if you want to copy to excel, the better way is to output from the server side. May be http://www.aspose.com/products/cells will help