# Javascript: reorder a large multidimensional array based on another array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that behaves like a spreadsheet.
First item it's a column header:

```
[
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    [ 1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 ],
    [ 5 ,  6 ,  7 ,  8 ],
    [...]
]
```

Order of the "columns" is defined by another array:

```
['C', 'A', 'D', 'B']
```

Expected result is:

```
[
    ['C', 'A', 'D', 'B'],
    [ 3 ,  1 ,  4 ,  2 ],
    [ 7 ,  5 ,  8 ,  6 ],
    [...]
]
```

Would `.map`, `.splice` and `.indexOf` be the best approach?
What about their performance on a 20k+ array?

Thanks!

Comment: 20K+ array, are you kidding? Users will never gonna visit your site if you use this in JS. instead try to use it in server

Comment: Don't worry. I'm using a library with deferRender for that.

Comment: Why would `.splice()` be used? What are current performance results? See [jQuery - Can threads/asynchronous be done?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068821/jquery-can-threads-asynchronous-be-done)

Comment: why not to use a configuration const instead of altering the array itself. 
I am sure, when you are using the array, instead of going by order of 0,1,2,3 go for the order that your configuration constant says, something like 2,0,3,1. It just how you understand the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function reorder(data, order) {
  let header = data[0];
  let orderIndex = order.map(i => header.indexOf(i));
  return data.map(row => orderIndex.map(i => row[i]));
}

let data = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    [ 1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 ],
    [ 5 ,  6 ,  7 ,  8 ],
];

let order = ['C', 'A', 'D', 'B'];

console.log(reorder(data, order));
```

As for performance... you'll need to test it.