# Executing 100K Promises in Javascript in small 50 Chunks

Tags: javascript, rest, promise

I have a function that makes a REST call to a service and returns a promise. lets call that function Execute(). The function takes an ID and sends the ID as a GET parameter to a REST end point which persists the ID in a mongoDB db with some additional info.

In the client, I will need to run "Execute" 100k times from IDs (0 to 100k) and show the status of each (Whether succeeded or failed).

I did the obvious and I created a loop from 0 to 100k and run execute passing "i. That caused my Chrome to eventually freeze running out of memory (insufficient resources). It also caused network congestion from all the rest calls going at the back end.

So I wanted to "chop" those 100k into manageable amount like 50 promises call each. And when those 50 are all done (whether failed or succeeded) I want to use **Promise.all([]).then** execute the next 50 until all the 100k are done. This way I control the network congestion and memory at the same time. However I can't seem to know how to shake this down. Here is my code.

```
let promises = []
for (let i = 0; i < 100000, i++)
    {
       promises.push(execute(i))
       if (i % 50 === 0) 
       {
          Promise.all(promises)
          .then  (a => updateStatus (a, true))
          .catch (a => updateStatus (a, false)) 

       }

    }
```

The asynchronous nature of Javascript will keep executing the rest of the loop and executing. I really don't want to put a timer to hold the loop every 50 iterations because this will block the UI and kind of turned my app synchronous. Any suggestions as to how I tackle this?

Thank You Very Much.

New to Javascript.

Comment: You should simply put your promises into an array of arrays. That way, you executer first array of 50 promises, then the second array,...

Comment: chunk your promises into a new array of arrays then simply process each sub array one at a time, which can easily be done with a reduce.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to put an `await` in front of that `Promise.all` call if your environment supports it… you must not continue synchronously with the loop after having created the 50 executions.

Comment: Bluebird's [`Promise.map()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) offers a concurrency feature that lets you specify how many requests are "in flight" at the same time.  This is more of a continuous design than chunking by 50.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639432/what-is-the-best-way-to-limit-concurrency-when-using-es6s-promise-all which has numerous suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With promises itself, this can be done only with recursion.

If you can use new version of Node.js, use async await, it will work as you expect, then you can use `await Promise.all(promises)`

If you cant, then there is nice library (called `Async`) that can execute 50 asynchronous calls at once with this method: https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#parallelLimit

It is even better than chunks, because if you have 1 slow callback in chunk, it will block everything else. With parallel limit, it just keep executing 50 callbacks all the time.
(however you can just pre-create chunks by 50 if you insist on them and use .series method)

Comment: Thanks. async await and generator functions did the trick for me. I wanted to "pause" the app for a while to allow stuff to get crunched  at the backend but I wanted the app to remain responsive.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `async/await` to perform asynchronous task in sequential order, schedule a call to the same function is the original array of contains elements, else return array of results

```js
let arr = Array.from({
  length: 2000
}, (_, i) => i);

let requests = arr.slice(0);

let results = [];

let fn = async(chunks, results) => {
  let curr;
  try {
    curr = await Promise.all(chunks.map(prop => 
             new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, prop))));
    results.push(curr);
    console.log(curr);
  } catch(err) {
    throw err
  }

  return curr !== undefined && requests.length 
         ? fn(requests.splice(0, 50), results) 
         : results
}

fn(requests.splice(0, 50), results)
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: See also [multiple, sequential fetch() Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034574/multiple-sequential-fetch-promise/)

Comment: [jQuery - Can threads/asynchronous be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068821/jquery-can-threads-asynchronous-be-done)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `promise` by function and push it an `array`.
After splitting the `array` in chunks and process with `reduce`.

Npm package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrency-promise